# Php could not redirect to certain pages

Tags: php, mysql

The following is my redirect function

```
function redirect_to($page = NULL) {
    if ($page != NULL) {
           header("page: {$page}");
           exit;
    }
 }
```

now the problem is when I call this function it does not work on some pages... Why ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Using the following will make the redirect work:

```
header("Location: {$page}");
```

Because `Page:` is not a valid HTTP header and gets ignored by browsers.

Comment: OK. But still its not working on some pages... It keeps redirecting to the same page over and over.

Comment: Then you most probably redirect to the same page, or you have wrong caching setup which leads to a cached response...

Comment: No... Redirecting to a different page.